# Google Classroom, delete teacher from course backend Error 500

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-classroom

I'm able to delete a teacher from a course but in this particular case I get this error (In [Classroom API Reference](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.teachers/delete?authuser=8) ):

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal error encountered.",
  "status": "INTERNAL"
 }
}
```

From my NodeJS app:

```
{ code: 500,
  message: 'Internal error encountered.',
  errors:
   [ { message: 'Internal error encountered.',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'backendError' } ],
  status: 'INTERNAL' }
```

The code (NodeJS app):

```
let classroom = google.classroom('v1');
let data = {
    auth     : auth,
    courseId : idCurso,
    userId   : emailDocente
};
classroom.courses.teachers.delete(data, (err, response) => {
    //...code
});
```

I get this error from the UI.
[image]

More Info:

- There are two teachers in the course: myemail@mydomain.com and
  admin@mydomain.com admin@mydomain.com is the owner.
- I need to remove myemail@mydomain.com The user is active and exists in GSuite Admin
  SDK.
- courseState is ACTIVE

Comment: There are 3 types of ERRORS in the given link? Are you getting all the 3 errors? If not, which one?

Comment: The first one as I mentioned in the OP is: When I try to delete a teacher from a course using the API Reference tool. The second one from my code when I call using the code I provided and the third one is deleting a teacher from google classroom UI.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by: the teacher was the owner of the google drive's folder. I had to delete from drive and the trash too. Developers should validate this and show a more clear message or delete the drive folder before deleting the teacher. Hope you guys update this. Thanks.

Update: I haven't been able to transfer ownership using drive API due to the fact that the user which I'm using to connect to the API doesn't have permission to change ownership I cannot have the real user to log in and change ownership because it's an automated process which runs every x minutes. I have to assign ownership of the drive folder to the user I connect to the API -not the real user- otherwise this will not work. I hope Google devs fix this.